# Washing before bracha on new clothes

Tags: halacha, blessing, clothing, netilat-yadayim-washing, shehecheyanu

According to my siddur (p. 231 of The Complete Artscroll Siddur), one makes a shehechyanu upon buying new clothes, and a malbish arumim upon putting them on once acquired. (I have heard from other sources that shehechyanu is made upon putting them on.)

But how would one make any bracha during or immediately after putting on clothes that require a full change? Is the procedure to make the bracha before putting on the clothes, or does one put on the clothes, ritually wash the hands, and then make the bracha?

Comment: I'm not aware of any thanksgiving blessing said before the event, and I fail to see why this would be different.

Comment: Actually you have to say it before you put it on, once you put it on there is a serious issue. The Mishna Berurah brings, that by a new Talis, you make the shecheyonu after the brachah of Tzitzit, and before putting it on. Same by eating a new fruit, we say shecheyonu before eating, and after blessing. Once you eat, you run into machlokes.

Comment: @lionscribe Actually, by the new fruit you say it after seeing the fruit not before. There is no "shehechiyanu" said on eating. By Tzitzit too, you say the blessing only after acquiring the Talis, not before. There is no "shehechiyanu" said on wearing.

Comment: By clothing, only when you purchase a ready to wear garmet do you make a brachah upon purchase. if you have to mend it, you make the brachah before wearing. (As for fruit, the Rama says that the custom is to make the brachah before eating, and not on first sight. ) Therefore the OP is asking, what to do if she cannot say the blessing when she is about to out it on, can she make afterwards. To which I commented, that there seems to be a machlokes, if you can make the brachah as long as the happiness is still there.

Comment: @lionscribe So we see no example of a thanksgiving blessing being said before the event, only customs to delay. You've proven my point.

Comment: @Double Yes, after the purchase BUT before the wearing, so the OP is correct.

Comment: @lion ???? Um... I don't know what to say.